# Love letter- using arrays to print message

Tags: java, arrays

I've been asked to create a program that stores series of suitable nouns, adjectives and verbs in arrays. These must be set up at the start of program run. Rather than ask the user, each time it generates letter it just chooses words at random from the appropriate array. The arrays are passed to methods that represent the templates.

I'm new to java, and this is what I have managed to get done below, however shows errors saying void cannot be converted to string for each print message part. I would be glad if someone can help me approach this simple question which i'm struggling on, I don't know if I am doing it correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public static void arrays()
   {
    String []noun = {"face", "eyes", "tender", "lips", "ears", "roses"};
    Random random = new Random();
    int rand1 = random.nextInt(noun.length);


    String []verb = {"enchant", "dazzle", "cuddle" , "lure", "desire", "dream" };
    Random random2 = new Random();
    int rand2 = random2.nextInt(verb.length);

    String []adjective = { "Alluring", "Angelic", "Adoring", "Appealing", "Attractive", "beautiful"};
    Random random3 = new Random();
    int rand3 = random3.nextInt(adjective.length);  
    printmessage (noun[rand1], verb[rand2], adjective[rand3]);      
}

// END arrays

 public static void printmessage(String noun, String verb, String adjective)
{

    System.out.println("I would love to " + verb + " " + adjective + " " + noun + "\n");

    System.out.println("Your are my " + noun + " " + adjective + " " + verb + "\n");

    System.out.println("you always look great in that " + noun + " ,as you always do, since your so " + adjective + "\n");

    System.out.println("I get butterflies when I see you in" + noun + " , you make me " + verb + " , in your " + adjective + " world" + "\n");
    }
 } // END class loveletter
```

Comment: one problem is that you are trying to return 4 results from a single method.  Only the first return will be evaluated, and the rest may cause errors (not sure offhand how the java parser would handle it).

Comment: [JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) doesn't return anything, it does **not** return `String`

Comment: I would have gone for `System.out.println(Stringparam)` for displaying first rather than with Swing components. Do you have to make it be a dialog window? If so, you should concatenate them and then display it, I believe.

Comment: How am i suppose to return all of them at once, because I am suppose to attach a string to each sentence or else it would give more errors. @Marshall Tigerus

Comment: Also, no statement are allowed/executed after `return` (`finally` aside)

Answer (score 3):

You've got some issues here, so let's walk through them.

First, the conceptual issue.  You shouldn't need to return anything from your `printmessage` method, as all you're doing is showing a message dialog.

Next, you don't do anything with those four `result` variables, and they would only last within the scope of that method.  That's to say, not very long.  I don't think you need them.

Next,  the technical issues:

- One `return` is all it takes for the code execution to halt.  If it were valid code, you would only get back `result1`.  Since we discussed earlier that you don't need to return anything from this method, remove the superfluous `return`s.
- `JOptionPane#showMessageDialog` returns `void`; that is to say, it returns nothing.  You can't assign a value of its return type to a variable, so the variables do you absolutely no good.  Remove the assignment and declarations.
- Don't forget to change the return type of your method to `void` instead of `String`.
- Clean up the call in `arrays()` so that it only calls `printmessage` at the end, and doesn't do anything else after that.

I leave the logical errors (I did notice some funky string concatenation and grammatical errors in there) as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Still getting errors, even though I acted on everything you said :/ I give up. Ive spent ages trying to solve this. Is anyone able to solve this code for me so its working? I'm fed up now. @makoto

Comment: So you've changed the return type of your method to `void`, removed the assignments to those `result` variables, removed the `return` statements, removed the assignment within `arrays` of the result of `printmessage`, and removed the subsequent `JOptionPane` after your call to `printmessage`?  And you're still getting errors?

Comment: I've edited the code, see above. I think ive changed what youve said, but still can you double check where i'm still going wrong. @Makoto